# how to set up cudf for cuda 9.0

Tags: python, pip, cudf

I have Cuda 9.0 version and 
I have tried

> pip install cudf==0.6.1

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cudf==0.6.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cudf==0.6.1

Comment: Did you see the [installation instructions](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf#installation), and the instructions on the [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/cudf/) ?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason why you can't update to cuda 10.x for the latest cudf...or even cuda 9.2 for cudf version 0.12?  I just think its a shame to be locked into cudf 0.6.1 when we're doing nightlies for v0.14

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the documentation?
`https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/blob/master/README.md`
You should use `conda` to install it.

Answer (score 0):

`cudf` 0.6.1 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/cudf/0.6.1/#files) 2 wheels, Python 3.6 and Python 3.7, both for 64-bit Linux. No source code.

Source code and installation instructions are at https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf#installation. You can try to install using `conda` or compile from sources.